# if column A has text and column G is blank then copy row to new spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a summary list for people in a downstream application to feed several of my production machines.  Each machine is going to have their own tab to request material, and I want all of their requests to be summarized on one tab (called "Core_Cutter_List").

So basically I am trying to create a VBA that will copy over a row from spreadsheet "2" into the next blank line on spreadsheet "Core_Cutter_List".  I want it to copy if there is text in column A and column G is blank.  I have limited knowledge of VBA.  The code that I found was able to only test for one of my criteria which was that column G is blank, but basically it runs through every single cell on my file.  Do you know how I can add the other criteria of column A having text in it so that it doesn't look through every cell on my sheet?  Thanks for any help!

```
Sub Test()
'
' Test Macro
'

  Sheets("2").Select

For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("G:G")
    If Cell.Value = "" Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Core_Cutting_List").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("2").Select
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need two conditions, then you should write them carefully in the `IF` statement with `And`:

Something like `If cell.Value = "" And Len(cell.Offset(0,-6)) Then` should be workable.

Using `Select` is a bit not advisable, but it works at the beginning - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  But that didn't work.  Nothing copied over to the other tab.

Answer (score 0):

The Sub bellow does the following

- Determine the last used row in Worksheets("2") based on values in column A
- Determine the last used col in Worksheets("2") based on values in row 1
- Determine the last used row in Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List") based on values in column A
- Loop through all used rows in Worksheets("2")

  - If the cell in col A is not empty And cell in col G is empty

    - Copy entire row to next empty row in Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")
    - Increment next empty row for Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")
  - Loop to the next used row in Worksheets("2")

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws1r As Range, ws2r As Range
    Dim ws1lr As Long, ws1lc As Long, ws2lr As Long, i As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

    ws1lr = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        'last row in "2"
    ws1lc = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last col in "2"
    ws2lr = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'last row in "Core_Cutter"

    For i = 1 To ws1lr

        If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) > 0 And Len(ws1.Cells(i, "G")) = 0 Then

            Set ws1r = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, ws1lc))
            Set ws2r = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(ws2lr, 1), ws2.Cells(ws2lr, ws1lc))

            ws2r.Value2 = ws1r.Value2
            ws2lr = ws2lr + 1
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

---

My test file

Worksheets("2")

[image: Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")]

Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

[image: Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  When I try to run the code it gives me an error saying "Compile Error:  Invalid Inside Procedure" when I run the debug it brings me up to the Option Explicit section of the code.  Do you know why it's bugging out?

Comment: Sure, somewhere in your module you have a Sub() defined inside another Sub(), or one sub is not closed off properly (using and "End Sub"). Not to spend your time cleaning up your current file, create a new test file with a small set of data, and the same sheet names, then add a new VBA standard module and test the code in the answer, then you may need to cleanup the module in your main file

Comment: So I tried this, but I still got an error.  I realized that I had my macro named, so I got rid of the naming function.  Then I got an error that said run time error '9' script out of range, and then it highlighted  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

Comment: In your file it looks for a sheet named "Core_Cutter_List" and it cannot find it (make sure it's spelled exactly like that - with underscores and not spaces between the words)

Comment: Sorry one more question...  I just realized a problem that I didn't think of.  There might be times where we update the macro before someone marks an order complete (which is my trigger for G being blank or not) but I don't want the order to copy over twice onto the core cutter list.  Any ideas on how to have it not copy values already on that list?

Comment: Do you have any unique identifiers within one row? (what's the easiest way to determine that we already have the row copied?)

Comment: I would say that if we did an & to combine columns A, C, and D that would show if it was unique or not.  But I'd rather that not show up on the spreadsheet if possible.

Comment: Great. This question can be closed - please accept the answer if it solves the initial request, and open a new question (with this code) asking specifically about not copying duplicate rows, with the details you just provided); The next one is a bit more involved but I'll get working on it now

Comment: Sorry,  How do I accept the answer to close the question?

Comment: No problem: to mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to green - [more details Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)